# String to Decimal Conversion in C# (Sharepoint)

Tags: 2007, development

Converting string to decimal seems to be a familiar question. But in my case the an error is throwing while I tried to convert a string value "10.00000000000" to decimal. 
I tried following codes

```
Decimal a = Convert.Todecimal("10.0000000000000000") ;
decimal a = decimal.Parse("10.0000000000000000");
```

but failed.

I think the problem is with the "zeros"(10.**0000000000000000**). Can any one knows why this produce an exception. I forget the error. But I will let you know that by tomorrow.

Can any one help.. please.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to SharePoint, so you may have better luck on http://stackoverflow.com/. Anyway, check the decimal separator on the machine, it could be the source of the error.

Answer (score 3):

I copy pasted your code and got a

> 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition of 'Todecimal'

and

> 'A local variable named a is already in defined in this scope'

Rewriting your code to a simple console app I didn't get any error at all:

```
        Decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal("10.0000000000000000");
        decimal b = decimal.Parse("10.0000000000000000");
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
        Console.Read();
```